# How to detect and log long time taking requests and connection timeout requests

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

question is pretty simple even if not so obvious.

I managing a website that's showing issues with **connection timeout**, making the web service unaccessible and not working properly when it happens.

The actual environment is WooCommerce on a self-managed secured VPS.

***php7, php-fpm***, wordpress 5.+, apache2, mysql, cPanel, centOs

For a couple of time the site became unreachable showing *Connection Timeout error*, even if all services was up and running.

### How to **track or log requests** originating the connection timeout error?

**For example, with an application ran on the server that:**

- log every requests that occurs with more than 30 seconds execution time
- the moment of the request
- the request URL.

Any software, wordpress, cPanel extension or service in order to detect the issue?

Comment: 30 seconds is a ridiculous long time. But my idea is that only the client will know when there's a time-out, and it's not easy to get that information onto the server. I normally use a [website monitoring service](https://hostingfacts.com/website-monitoring-services/) to check how my website is performing.

Comment: Yes that seems a legit need, but in my case I think the solution has to be found on the server, for example, if access_log would have more informations, like the request execution duration, I would be able to grep that and obtain what I need. Also because these data could really help in many scenarios, not just connection timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution in matter of detecting the situation when it happens.

The key information can be found in PHP-FPM log (deducted that by the fact that restarting PHP-FPM and not Apache2 was solving the problem, due to a probable PHP-FPM thread appended).

i.e., in a cPanel enviroment you would find the log at the path:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php$$/root/usr/var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

In the file the following lines are noteful:

```
[Tue Jul 16 09:55:30.677693 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17283] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 162.158.91.192:16946] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://www.example.com/my-resource.php
[Tue Jul 16 10:00:30.738947 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17283] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 162.158.91.192:16946] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://www.example.com/my-resource.php
```

So I've been able to inspect the shown resource and replicate and solve the issue.